# Text file parsing C++

Tags: c++, arrays, text-parsing

I have been trying to parse through a text file in c++ to read the numbers that are contained within the file. The number of integers on each line and the number of lines is not know. When all the integers are read they will save that integer followed by a ',' and the running total of that line. This will then be outputted to a file chosen by the user. The code I have written is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i=0,b = 0,num = 100;
int *s1;
string myfilename, mystring, filename;

cout << "Enter the name of the file to open:" << endl;
cin >> myfilename;
cout << "Enter the name of the output file" << endl;
cin >> filename;

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile("C:\\Users\\Aidan Howie\\Documents\\University\\Second Year\\C++\\" + filename + ".txt");

inFile.open("C:\\Users\\Aidan Howie\\Documents\\University\\Second Year\\C++\\" + myfilename + ".txt");
if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "Cannot open file" << endl;
    return -1;
}
while (!inFile.eof())
{
    s1 = new int[num];
    for (i = 0; i < s1; i++)
    {
        cout << i << "," << (i + b) / s1;
        b = i+b;
        cout << endl;
    }

}

inFile.close();
system("PAUSE");
```

}

However receive the error:

```
error C2446: '<' : no conversion from 'int *' to 'int'
```

Can anyone explain how to fix this and whether there is an easier way for me to read the unknown integers on the file

Comment: The error is simple, you cannot convert a pointer to integer to an integer. If you want to use the int values within the int pointer then you would use `*si` or `si[index]`. Also I don't see you setting any values to `s1`. You are only initializing it with the new operator which could either give you `0` or garbage values.

Comment: Nothing you do in the while loop makes much sense to me. Try to go step by step if you are confused about how to do it. 1) Try to read every line from a file and output what you read to cout. 2) try to read a file with one integer on each line and output the numbers you read. 3) try to write the numbers you read in 2 to an output file. 4) try to read in a file with "number, number" on each line and output just the second 5) output the sum of the two value on each line from 4. 6) do the task you have

Answer (score 0):

`s1` is a pointer to an int, while `i` is an int. So essentially what you're doing is checking if `6 < 0x55ddab`.

The right way to do it is: `i < *s1`

Also, don't forget to `delete s1` before your while loop repeats.

Also, I'm just going to put a note that what you're doing makes no sense, nonetheless, using `i < *s1` will fix your error.

Comment: `i < *s1` makes no sense either.

Comment: @CareyGregory, in itself, knowing that `s1` is a pointer to an integer, and `i` is an integer, it makes perfect sense. It's taking int `i` and the int that `s1` is pointing to and comparing them.

Comment: I meant in the context of his code. Changing `i < s1` to `i < *s1` would leave it just as broken.

Answer (score 0):

`s1` is an array of `ints`, which means that when you use the name `s1` without an index, it is a pointer. Therefore, your comparison of `i < s1` is asking if `i` is less than the address of `s1`, and that's not a valid comparison. Your line of code should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

Also, `inFile.eof()` isn't doing what you think it is. The only way you're going to get an EOF on `inFile` is if the user types ctrl+D. You should have the user enter some sentinel value to signal the end of input; for example, 0 or -1 or some other otherwise invalid value.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is count how many integers are in the file and then output the first number followed by a ',' with the running total of the numbers on the line. I can see now my code doesn't do anything along them lines however is there any way I can do this

Comment: @user3364345 you at no point read any data from `inFile`, doing so would be a good start

Comment: I know I have been through exercises reading files and I have managed them okay, however I can't seem to read a file with unknown values and print each of them to the output file. @PeterT

Comment: @user3364345 how did you read from files in previous exercises?

Comment: Using the getline function for reading the whole file and when I knew how long the integer file was the while(infile>>a>>b>>..). @PeterT

Comment: @user3364345 But as PeterT pointed out, at no point do you read from `inFile` so I'm not sure why you expect input to happen.